# How can I install dependencies for libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.38) on debian buster?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, apt-get

I want to install php8.2 packages on my debian buster machine, but when I try to install I got following error message:

```
# apt install php8.2-fpm
Reading package lists... Done
...
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php8.2-fpm : Depends: php8.2-cli but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.38) but 10.32-5+deb10u1 is to be installed
              Depends: libsodium23 (>= 1.0.18) but 1.0.17-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm using the repository:  `https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease`

But it seems the libpcre2-8-0 package > v.10.38 is not in the repos by buster.

So what is here best way to resolve the dependencies break? Have I to use sid repositories? (I don't know if I got some problems with this repo)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with:

Just check the version of libpcre2-8-0 package

```
apt poilicy libpcre2-8-0
```

and then install package manually, but dont know why this isn't worked by just installing the php8.x packages automatically.

```bash
apt install libpcre2-8-0=10.40-1+0~20220713.16+debian10~1.gbpb6cec5
#same with apt policy libzip4 and libsodium
apt install libzip4=1.7.3-1+0~20210114.10+debian10~1.gbp4c125d
apt install libsodium23=1.0.18-1+0~20191009.1+debian10~1.gbpb6823f
# install php
apt install php8.2 php8.2-cli php8.2-{bz2,curl,mbstring,intl}
apt install php8.2-fpm
```